# Динамическое изменение направления owl-carousel 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

Такая проблема с настройкой owl-carousel v2.Изначально нужно было сделать бесконечный слайдер. Взяли owl, но он для этого использует клонирование элементов, а нам это категорически не надо. Решили сделать так: как только доходим до последего слайда, то меняем направление свойством rtl:true.
Только возникла проблема,как это свойство задать динамически. Варианты, найденные в интернете зачастую выдают различные ошибки и не дают нужного результата.
Мб кто-то сталкивался, или посоветует слайдер делающий это без клонирования?

Я пробовал сделать так, но это выдает ошибку(

```
 hitsSldier.on('changed.owl.carousel', function (event) {

 var  slidePrePage = event.page.size;
 var  count  = event.item.count;
 var  currentSlide = event.item.index;

 if(currentSlide == count-slidePrePage){
 var carousel = hitsSldier.data('owl.carousel');
 carousel.settings.rtl = true;

 hitsSldier.trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
 }
 });
```

Comment: А чем вас не устроило клонирование,  мешает чему-то ?

Comment: да, при клонировании есть косяк большой при интеграции с битриксом. Нужна реализация без задваивания id, т.е без клонирования.